# Open folder with applescript (file path with spaces)

Tags: operating-system, applescript, directory, filepath

I think my problem is the spaces in the file path. But I can't get it to work.

Here is the folder path I want to open: `/Users/username/Library/Speech/Speakable Items`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your path is correct it would be:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open ("/Users/username/Library/Speech/Speakable Items" as POSIX file)
end tell
```

Comment: I get the error: error "Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000 The file path should be correct because I dragged it straight from finder into AppleScript and it matches what I thought it should be.

Comment: OK - try it with an easier path first, e.g. `tell application "Finder"
    open ("/Users/username/Documents" as POSIX file)
end tell` - that works OK for me - I couldn't try `Speakable Items` as I don't seem to have that folder anywhere. I did try it with a path with spaces though and that seems to work OK too.

Comment: Duh!!!! Forgot to change "username" back to my name! How stupid of me! Thanks So Much!

Comment: Aha - good catch - I was mystified as to why it didn't work for you!